# To find height of a binary search tree

Tags: height, binary-search-tree, infinite-loop

/*
     * To find the Height of a BST tree
     */

```
public void findHeight(){
    if(this.root == null){
        System.out.println("BST Tree is Empty ");
    }
    else
        findHeight(this.root);
}
public int findHeight(Tnode temp){
    if(temp == null){
        System.out.println("BST Tree is Empty ");
        return  -1;
    }
    else{
        return 1 + Math.max(findHeight(temp.getLeft()) ,findHeight(temp.getRight()) ) ;
    }
}
```

Program is running infinitely.Not able to find the reason , It would be helpfull ,if some one guides me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the findHeight() function doesn't return anything? Are you expecting anything from that function? Posting more code would help.

Answer (score 0):

"BST Tree is Empty" will also be printed at every terminal leaf of the tree.

To find out what's going on, you could add some debugging output:

```
private spaces(int len){
    String s = "       ";

    while (s.Length < len) {
      s += "        ";
    }

   return s.substring(0, len);
}

public int findHeight(Tnode temp, int nesting, String msg){
    String margin = spaces(2*nesting);

    if(temp == null){
        System.out.println(margin + msg + ": no sub-tree to explore");
        return  -1;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(margin + msg);
        int hl = findHeight(temp.getLeft(), nesting + 1, "left");
        int hr = findHeight(temp.getRight(), nesting + 1, "right");

        return 1 + (hl >= hr ? hl : hr) ;
    }
}
```

Your endless recursion might be due to some error in your tree structure. If your left/right child references are never null, the recursion won't terminate.